# tinyXML xml parsing with c++ without the xml file

Tags: c++, tinyxml

I am trying to parse xml from a message like this:

```
char * data = message.c_str ();
```

How can I create the xmlDoc with the string or a char array data, meaning without the xml file?

Answer (score 4):

I think you can do so via the [Parse](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/classTiXmlDocument.html#17ebabe36926ef398e78dec0d0ad0378) method in TiXmlDocument. So something like:

```
TiXmlDocument doc;
doc.Parse((const char*)data, 0, TIXML_ENCODING_UTF8);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& in, TiXmlNode& base);` function defined in `tinyxml.h`:

> C++ style input:
>
> based on `std::istream operator>>`
>
> Reads XML from a stream, making it
>   useful for network transmission. The
>   tricky part is knowing when the XML
>   document is complete, since there will
>   almost certainly be other data in the
>   stream. TinyXML will assume the XML
>   data is complete after it reads the
>   root element. Put another way,
>   documents that are ill-constructed
>   with more than one root element will
>   not read correctly. Also note that
>   operator>> is somewhat slower than
>   Parse, due to both implementation of
>   the STL and limitations of TinyXML.